# Probability the walk terminates

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, martingales, stopping-times

Consider a random walk $S_n=S_0+\sum^b_{i=1}X_i$ with i.i.d steps $X_i$ taking value $4$ and $-7$ with probabilities $\frac{7}{11}$ and $\frac{4}{11}$ respectively.

Suppose the walk starts at $S_0=3$, and terminates whenever the boundaries at $1600$ or $-4900$ are reached or exceeded for the first time. Determine the probability that the walk terminates at or beyond the right boundary $1600$ using the optional stopping theorem.

My attempt to solve this:

The random walk $S_n$ terminates at time $T$ such that $S_T=1600$ or $S_T=-4900$

Assuming validity of $E[S_{T}]=E[S_0]$, we can express $E[S_{T}]$ as $1600P+(-4900)(1-P)$ using the fact that $S_0=3$ with probability $1$ hence $$1600P-4900(1-P)=3\Leftrightarrow 6500P=4903\Leftrightarrow P=0.75$$

So the probability the walk terminates at or beyond $1600$ is $0.75$

Is this correct?

Comment: You shouldn't use $S_{1600}$ to represent the first hitting time of $1600$

Comment: @JoseAvilez but is the solution correct? Also, what should I use as an index then?

Comment: You should properly define a stopping time $\tau$. Once you show the conditions of optional stopping hold you get $E(S_\tau) = E(S_0)$, which you can use to find the relevant probability.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I edited it, it should be correct now?

Comment: This is incorrect because you have not considered cases such as $S_T=1601$ or $S_T=1602$.  You will be able to get accurate upper and lower bounds on the desired probability (both upper and lower bounds are close to 0.75), but I would be surprised if you can get an exact value.